# paddler: undefined method `list_financial_event_groups' for #<MWS::Reports::Client:0x000000031ad2b0>

Tags: ruby, amazon-mws, mws

I'm calling an API `list_financial_event_groups` using peddler and its says it is undefined method. Even though the API call is present in paddler documentation.

I'm calling the `get_report_list` with same client and its working fine. I don't know why it says undefined only for `list_financial_event_groups` and not for `get_report_list`.

Anybody can please help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here to learn how to improve your questions (formatting, proofreading, providing code etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a stupid mistake by myself. I'm initialising the wrong client library this `@client = MWS::Reports::Client.new` instead of `@client = MWS::Finances::Client.new`.